# Javascript Alert message runtime error Object Expected

Tags: javascript, runtime, alert

Ok .. this is a strange one as I have NOT seen this before. I have an application that is strictly a Service ... no browser involved ... and all I want to do is use alert(); for debugging. The only problem is that it causes an Object Expected error even if it is a simple alert("Show me!");

Remember ... this code is not attached to any form or browser. So what am I missing? I thought I could use the alert call at any time in Javascript ... Please folks, help a poor programmer out!

Thank you in advance, 
Eric

Comment: What is running the code if not a browser? Is this node or something?

Comment: It's a service type of call. The code on the front side of things is a form scraper for information to pass into the javascript guts of the service so to speak. I am trying to debug it using alert but it is not working ....

Comment: Once again, can you clarify the environment you're working in? If you're not running in a browser, alert likely doesn't exist. You may be able to use `console.log` to the same effect. When you execute this code, how are you running it? Is there an application you're executing? Is it node? PhantomJS?

Comment: Environment is not your text editor. Javascript isn't compiled; by its nature it has to be executed by another application. Are you opening the javascript file on a web page in a browser? Are you running an executable on your local machine? When you're testing it you must be executing it in SOME environment... we need to know what that environment is. Are you running a batch file? Can you open it and paste the contents? There has to be some way to find out what is executing your code.

Comment: Batch file executes the javascript files. 

I have figured a way to debug it ... although it is very convoluted. I have to write out the information I want to see to a text file ...

Answer (score 7):

Like praneeth already suggested in his reply, it is a Windows WScript thing, or rather just context in which the script is being run in.

This also works and isn't quite as verbose as what praneeth offered:

```
WScript.Echo("Hello");
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are executing this script on a windows machine you can do like this in javascript/Jscript

Var Shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
Shell.Popup("Your Debug message");

Comment: may i suggest you change **Var** to **var** because JavaScript is case sensitive. the code you posted might throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

The alert() method is one of the JavaScript browser **Window** object's methods which displays an alert box with a message and an OK button.

The window object represents an open window in a browser. If a document contain frames, the browser creates one window object for the HTML document and one additional window object for each frame.

I believe that in the specified case, the error means that the Window expected object has not been found.

Comment: Thank you Tolis. That makes perfect sense ... then how do I get an alert to show if there is no Window object immediately available?

Comment: Do not test your JavaScript code through alerts.. You should use a JavaScript unit testing framework like Qunit http://qunitjs.com/

Comment: No ... I am not testing ... debugging. I am not sure how QUnit would work with the functionality I am trying to figure out. The problem is not being able to see what's going on while the code is processing. I can't debug it properly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `window.alert("show me");`?

Since alert() is a Window object method.

Comment: What platform / JavaScript interpreter are you using?

Comment: Excellent question. This code was not written by our shop and I do not see ANYWHERE in the code what platform it is using. We are editing it through Notepad ++.

Comment: Maybe some other files with that code file would give you a hint. Try to see if there are any library files within the code. Also this might be a stupid question, but does this current file have a .js extension?

Comment: Yes. It has the .js extension. I have looked around for other library files but all this code is detached from the parent window. So I am not sure if including any other file would be helpful ...

Comment: No I was hoping you could find some library files to find out what platform / framework you're using. Otherwise it would be almost impossible to help you out.

Comment: I think he is trying to run the .js file directly on the machine, as in running it under the WScript.Exe (WSH environment.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running in a browser, you might have better luck using the `console.log` method - again, it's very hard to tell you specifically what to do without any detail of what environment you're executing the script in.

Comment: A batch file executes the javascript files. Sorry I was unclear about it earlier.

Comment: Can you paste the contents?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do that ... kind of a particular shop I am working out of ... I have figured out how to debug though. It's a pain in the neck, but at least I get to see what's happening with the data as it moves through the code.

I am having to write out the object information to a text file to see what happens to it as it moves through. I apologize for the frustration ... and I do appreciate the help ...

Comment: Just the contents of the batch file. Even the executable name without parameters.